# Webextension DataView constructor not working

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm using Firefox 50.1.0. I created the following web extension:

manifest.json

```
{
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://exifdata.com/"], // sample site
      "js": ["index.js"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

index.js

```
function fileToDataView(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    console.log(new DataView(e.target.result)); // empty Dataview
  };
  reader.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log(error); // no error occurs
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]')

nodes.forEach(function (node) {
  node.onchange = function (event) {
    fileToDataView(event.target.files[0]);
  }
})
```

When I upload a file the function `fileToDataView` is called.

In this function the reader.onload logs the `new DataView()` but it's an empty dataView object instead of the dataView with the parameter `e.target.result`.

I am doing something wrong? The problem is that I want to call `.getInt8()` after but the error `is not a function` is thrown.

Full code is [here](https://github.com/Piu130/extension-image-properties-viewer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid this is simply a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1333073) in Firefox. I am in the process of fixing this for Firefox 54.

If you use different TypedArrays to wrap your ArrayBuffer instead of DataView it should work.